# Manipulating "spaces" to swipe faster

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, mission-control

When making an app how do I communicate to spaces to change from desktop 1 to desktop 2?

Do I do it through the plist? com.apple.spaces.plist seems to record ever time I open a new space, but where do I go from there? Additionally I noticed that if you open Mission Control in terminal with a 1, 2, 3 it will activate the various window settings.

Would be nice if there was a clear class I could extend do I just search around in the framework for this?

Just kind of need a direction on this, thanks.

---

New update going through defaults I found:

```
    "workspaces-auto-swoosh" = 1;
    "workspaces-swoosh-animation-off" = 0;
```

Sadly when I change them to 0 or 1 no noticeable change happens.

---

Update number three,

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled
```

That disables mission control, but what's weird is if I look in the com.apple.dock.plist there is no mention of mcx. How do people find these commands if they aren't mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Last time I checked, Spaces is woefully under- documented and controllable.

Comment: Yeah that seems to becoming more and more true. Not just for spaces but for all animations it seems.